# Comparing an single array-element containing a long string and a simple txt-file

Tags: bash, shell

I know, this should be rather trivial but I don't know why I'm stucked. The problem: A simple `/file.txt` with

```
aaa bbb
ccc ddd
```

shall be checked against an array of string

```
declare -a strings
strings[0]="aaa bbb"
strings[1]="$strings[0]"
strings[1]+="ccc ddd"
```

within a simple function

```
status "$path_to_file" "${strings[@]}"
```

and definition like this.

```
function status {
  local conf=$1
  shift
  local statuses=("$@")
  local len="${#statuses[@]}"
  for ((i=0; i<len; i++)); do
    if [[ "$(< "$conf")" == "${statuses[${i}]}" ]]; then
      logger "$0 status success"
      return $i
    fi
    #echo "${statuses[${i}]}"
  done
  logger "$0 status fail"
  return `expr $len - 1`
}
```

The line `if [[ "$(< "$conf")" == "${statuses[${i}]}" ]]; then` troubles me. It does not expand like a string but rather like

```
\a\a\a \b\b\b
\c\c\c \d\d\d
```

Expanding with backslashes `\` the string can't be compared `==`. Why is that?

Comment: which side expands like that? can you make a [more minimal example that shows your problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why the expanding shows itself with the backslashes, however, this is not your problem.

The problem here is that `"$(< "$conf")"` will return all the data in the file, and thus the two strings in the "if" will be inherently different.

You can check that the following script return success, despite the frightening "\a\a\a" that is still showed through bash -x.

```
 #!/bin/bash -x 
function status {
  local conf=$1
  shift
  local statuses=("$@")
  echo $statuses
  local len="${#statuses[@]}"
  for ((i=0; i<len; i++)); do
    if [[ $(head -n `expr $i + 1` $conf | tail -n 1) == "${statuses[$i]}" ]]; then
      logger "$0 status success"
      return $i
    fi
    #echo "${statuses[${i}]}"
  done
  logger "$0 status fail"
  return `expr $len - 1`
}
declare -a strings
strings[0]="aaa bbb"
strings[1]="$strings"
strings[1]+=" ccc ddd"

path_to_file=./data
status "$path_to_file" "${strings[@]}"
```

when ./data is a file containing:

```
aaa bbb
ccc ddd
```

Comment: It was this line ```strings[1]="$strings"``` which helped. My line ```strings[1]="$strings[0]"``` is not working correctly.